# VB.NET --- How can I efficiently obtain a two dimensional array result from a SQL Server query?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, multidimensional-array

I'm attempting to make a generic query executer function. I want to be able to send it a query string and have it return a two-dimensional array containing the results. Below is my code for how to do it with a (9,x) array. How can I do it with an (y,x) sized array? Also, I feel like there must be a more efficient way to do this...

```vb
   Dim right As Integer = 0
    dbConn = New SqlConnection("hidden for security purposes")
    MyCommand = New SqlCommand(queryString, dbConn)
    dbConn.Open()
    Dim resultArray(9, 0) As String
    MyDataReader = MyCommand.ExecuteReader()

    While (MyDataReader.Read())
        For i = 0 To 9
            If IsDBNull(MyDataReader(i)) Then
                'resultArray(i, UBound(resultArray, 2)) = ""
            Else
                resultArray(i, UBound(resultArray, 2)) = MyDataReader(i)

            End If
        Next

        ReDim Preserve resultArray(9, UBound(resultArray, 2) + 1)
    End While
    ReDim Preserve resultArray(9, UBound(resultArray, 2) - 1)
    MyDataReader.Close()
    dbConn.Close()

Return resultArray
```

Comment: if you don't provide a mechanism to accept query parameters separate from the query text, you're code is broken and you are promoting an anti-pattern

Comment: @Joel how do you know there are any query parameters? Maybe it's simply `SELECT x,y FROM table;`?

Comment: @AaronBertrand, See Silver's previous question from an hour ago.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10981183/design-decision-vb-net-should-i-create-a-class-or-module-to-easily-connect-to/10981900#10981900

Comment: @SteveDog ok, that's helpful context, but I'm not sure how it applies to this question, which wouldn't change regardless of how the reader is assembled.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn is right, this is a really bad design.  It's one thing if it's just a quick hack, but if this is part of a foundational framework upon which a large application will rest, it's not at all a good idea to have your entire data access layer consist of a single static method.  That being said, this would be easier to do if you just filled a DataSet rather than using the data reader.  In fact, if you insist on doing it this way, it would be far better to at least return a data set instead of a 2D array.

Comment: @Silver - because you called it a **generic** query execution function

Comment: So, what I initially thought of as a time saver really isn't? Should I just drop this whole line of thinking? Or should I add an additional parameter (an array of all the parameters) to this function... but then it needs to also know if it's a simple select or some sort of insert/update query huh...? I think I'll just drop this idea

Comment: @Silver - adding an array for parameters is good enough.

Comment: One other thing: think for a minute whether your connection will be closed or left hanging open if an exception occurs when executing the query.

Comment: Ah! Definitely need some try/catch block!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```vb
Public Function GetData(ByVal queryString As String, ByVal addParameters As Action(Of SqlParameterCollection) As DataTable
    Dim result As New DataTable()
    Using cn As New SqlConnection(" connection string "), _
          cmd As New SqlCommand(queryString, cn)

       addParameters(cmd.Parameters)

       cn.Open()
       Using rdr As SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
          result.Load(rdr)
       End Using
   End Using
   Return result
End Function
```

For a query with no parameters, call it like this:

```
Dim result = GetData("Select * from Table", Sub(p) Exit Sub)
```

Or if you do have a parameter:

```
Dim result = GetData("Select * from Table Where ID= @ID", _
    Sub(p)
        p.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 12345
    End Sub)
```

Comment: One last question (sorry!) I've already implemented your answer in the code for querying the SQL database. Now I'm tweaking it to be used for the Access database. Using cn As New OleDbConnection("connection string"_ cmd As New OleDbCommand(queryString, objConn) addParameters(cmd.Parameters) However, it doesn't like the cmd.Parameters being a SQLParameterCollection (how on earth do I keep the spacing in this comment?)

Comment: Unless I add an additional parameter! Wooo! (I think it'll work!)

Comment: Use an OleDbParameterCollection instead of SqlParameterCollection in the function signature.

Answer (score 0):

I caution that this is a bad idea, but if you must do this, I would suggest returning a data set instead of an array:

```
Private Function getDataSet(ByVal queryString As String) As DataSet
    Dim data As New DataSet()
    Using dbConn As New SqlConnection("hidden for security purposes")
        dbConn.Open()
        Using MyCommand As New SqlCommand(queryString, dbConn)
            Using adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(MyCommand)
                adapter.Fill(data)
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
    Return data
End Function
```

If you don't want the data set, you could return just the first table in the data set (which is essentially a 2D array of the data, but with a lot more functionality and metadata):

```
Private Function getDataTable(ByVal queryString As String) As DataTable
    Dim data As New DataSet()
    Using dbConn As New SqlConnection("hidden for security purposes")
        dbConn.Open()
        Using MyCommand As New SqlCommand(queryString, dbConn)
            Using adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(MyCommand)
                adapter.Fill(data)
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
    Return data.Tables(0)
End Function
```

Or, if you must have a 2D array of strings, you could still do it easier by filling a data set internally and then converting that to an array:

```
Private Function getDataArray(ByVal queryString As String) As String()()
    Dim rows As List(Of String()) = New List(Of String())
    Using dbConn As New SqlConnection("hidden for security purposes")
        dbConn.Open()
        Using MyCommand As New SqlCommand(queryString, dbConn)
            Using adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(MyCommand)
                Dim data As New DataSet()
                adapter.Fill(data)
                For Each row As DataRow In data.Tables(0).Rows
                    Dim items(row.ItemArray.Length) As String
                    For i As Integer = 0 To row.ItemArray.Length - 1
                        items(i) = row.ItemArray(i).ToString()
                    Next
                    rows.Add(items)
                Next
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
    Return rows.ToArray()
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier and more efficient to use a List and to swap x and y

```
Dim result = new List(Of String())
```

A List grows automatically.

```
While (MyDataReader.Read())
    Dim row = new String(MyDataReader.FieldCount - 1)
    For i = 0 To MyDataReader.FieldCount - 1
        row(i) = MyDataReader(i).ToString()
    Next
    result.Add(row)
End While
```